# Check if webpage loaded after opening it as a process in C#?

Tags: c#, html

I am opening different browsers using

```
ProcessStartInfo startBrowser = new ProcessStartInfo(internetbrowser, website);
Process.Start(startBrowser);
```

Which works great.  However, I need to also know when the webpage has loaded.  Is there a way that I can check this? Or even better, fire an event when the page is fully loaded?

Thanks

Comment: not sure if its possible, but you could try and inject jquery if it doesnt exist and call document ready

Answer (score 0):

You didn't noticed in your question which browser you want to use.

If you use the `Internet Explorer` than I have a good solution.
You need a reference to the `SHDocVw.dll` for the example below.

Tested code example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            InternetExplorer explorer = new InternetExplorer();

            object Empty = 0;
            object URL = "http://www.yourwebsite.com"; // Here your URL

            // There are many more events.. But we need this one:
            explorer.DocumentComplete += ExplorerOnDocumentComplete; 

            explorer.Visible = true; // If you wish to see the IE, set it to true.

            // Navigate to the provided URL
            explorer.Navigate2(ref URL, ref Empty, ref Empty, ref Empty, ref Empty);

}

private void ExplorerOnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object url)
{
            // The document loaded completly. 
            // Do your work here.
}
```

Comment: I currently use IE, firefox and chrome, which is why I open them as processes.